# Add application menu entries in Fedora 34

Tags: fedora, gnome, desktop

After upgrading to Fedora 34, the `Activities` menu disappeared and this new `Applications` menu has taken its place in the upper left corner. There is no entry in the menu for the basic gnome terminal (or any terminal of any kind). So to start a terminal, the only way is to browse in the `Files` app to `/usr/bin/` and start the terminal from its binary file. Since there is no longer an "add to favorites" features, I can't add anything to this new-and-incomplete menu. How can I conveniently start a terminal, or any other program that has been disregarded during construction of the `Applications` menu?

[image: fedora 34 desktop]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you logged into the "GNOME Classic" shell (GNOME "skin" intended to look like the old GNOME 2) instead of the "standard" GNOME. Log out and on the login screen click on the settings button (shown only after you select a user) in the right bottom corner and select *GNOME* instead of *GNOME Classic*.

[image]

If you don't see *GNOME* there it's possible that something went wrong during the upgrade and some packages (for example `gnome-shell`) were removed. The easiest way to make sure you have everything needed is to reinstall the entire *Fedora Workstation* group using

```
sudo dnf group install "Fedora Workstation"
```

Comment: This looks like it should work but I can't login as shown in the screenshot because the workstation is headless and I'm accessing it via `tigervnc`. So this problem is not related to the upgrade, rather it is caused by a change in my configuration where I started using the recommended `systemctl start vncserver@:1` instead of the old (direct) shell command. Somewhere in the guts of tigervnc it chooses the gnome shell during silent login. Of course the documentation mentions nothing about gnome shell selection. So I filed a [bug on github](https://github.com/TigerVNC/tigervnc/issues/1329).

Comment: It turns out there is a configuration doc hidden in /usr/share like a sneaky easter egg, which explains how to specify the gnome shell. Of course it's not referenced in the man page. Updating the bug report...

Answer (score 0):

Click on the `Activities` button on the upper left hand, click on the square of dots to select "other applications", click right on the application of interest and `Add to favorites`. You can also use the `Search` area in top.

Comment: The whole reason I am asking this question is because there is no longer an `Activities` menu. As you can see in the screenshot, the `Activities` menu has been replaced by this new `Applications` menu. So the normal workflow you suggest, which I always used before, is no longer possible. What can I do now?